# Windows Server 2003 Multiple versions of same file by user name

Tags: windows, file, versions

I'm helping a client with an issue on his server and I'm  coming across something I have not seen before.

There appear to be multiple versions of shared files that are named with the windows logon name of the user plus some type of version number.  Such as:

myfile(jsmith v3).ini

myfile(jdoe v7).ini

myfile.ini

Can anyone tell me what feature is causing this and perhaps why? I've searched for this but either I'm not using applicable search terms or I'm entirely looking in the wrong place.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this went away and was the result of some funky custom scripting the client had run.  Thanks for anyone who read this.